# C# Background worker передать строку в ReportProgress

Tags: c#, progress-bar, backgroundworker

нужно в прогрессбар передавать процент, а в TextBlock имя текущего файла.
передаю int и строку. делаю так:

```
void bgw_progressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string[] s = (string[])e.UserState;
    prbar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    currFileNametb.Text = s[0];
}

bgw.ReportProgress((i / fullFilePathes.Count) * 100, fullFilePathes[i]);
```

потом так:

```
public class progressObject{
    public string fname { get; set; }
}

void bgw_progressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    prbar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    progressObject po = e.UserState as progressObject;
    currFileNametb.Text = po.fname;
}

bgw.ReportProgress((i / fullFilePathes.Count) * 100,  new progressObject { fname=fullFilePathes[i]});
```

получаю "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."
т.е. передаваемый UserState пустой.
как правильно передать строку вместе с числом?

Comment: а что за операцию выполняете

Comment: Парсю docx файлы

Comment: Оба варианта кода рабочие. В какой строке происходит исключение? Какой объект равен null?

Comment: currFileNametb.Text = s[0]; и currFileNametb.Text = po.fname;

Comment: если качаете то может https://metanit.com/sharp/net/2.1.php и там уже есть событие прогресса все просто легко

Comment: Нет. Я с диска беру файлы, парсю, и нужно выводить процент в прогресс бар и имя текущего файла. Как при установке программы на винде

Comment: @axmed2004, я могу ошибаться, но у двух строк, в которых у Вас происходит NRE есть нечто одинаковое -- currFileNametb.Text, это позволяет предполагать, что null равен именно currFileNametb

Comment: @Serafim Prozorov нет, сделал currFileNametb.Text = e.ProgressPercentage+" %";  работает